# Inputfile for sqlplus

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sqlplus

I have some problems with sqlplus and oracle. I have a piece of code where I open sqlcmd and give it a inputfile over the parameter `-i` with all SQL-Statements I need. Before that I open a cmd-window with java and over the cmd-window I open sqlcmd. Sounds not that smart, but couldn't figure out how to start sqlcmd directly with the parameters below without using the cmd-window.

the call of sqlcmd looks like this:

```
sqlcmd -S [Servername] -i input_file
```

The input file contains basic sql-statements like the usual select, from, where clause. It works really great and does the job, but now i need to translate it to an oracle-database.

My question here: is there something similar like the Parameter `-i` for sqlplus for oracle database?

```
sqlplus usr/password@database_name
```

That's how far I am and I am wondering if I can extend that line, so I can read in an input file with sql-statements.

thanks in advance

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_three.htm#i1169374 simply running `sqlplus -help` would have shown you that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute a SQL*Plus script on the command line by prefixing it with an `@` sign

```
sqlplus username/password@tns_alias @your_script_here.sql
```